# Reading non-standard excel file with C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

What do i mean by 'non-standard'?

Take a look at these images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3KsI.jpg

The first one is the non-standard excel file. I'm pretty sure it's not an excel file, but the file's extension is .xls and for some reason Excel can open it, and understand it's structure.

The second image is the same file after it was opened in excel, and saved out to .xls (97-2003).

If excel can open it, and view it correctly, i should be able to do as well. Any tips how to approach this?

I have to mention that, my app have to use and read the non-standard excel files, because otherwise the user have to open the files one-by-one in (excel/libre office) and save it out in a correct format, which i would like to avoid for convenience.

Comment: All I see is blonde, brunette, redhead...
Joking aside, what actually happens when you attempt to load said non-standard file like you would a standard excel file in code?

Comment: Looks to me as you have an .xls file that originally wasn't an excel file and has been renamed to .xls.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "non-standard Excel file", but there are fakes. Some web sites try to fake Excel exporting by sending CSV or HTML tables with an `xls` extension. Excel can detect and import such text files as *text* or *HTML*. Have you tried opening the suspicious file with a text editor?

Comment: BTW the `xls` format is a deprecated binary format, requires Excel or an OLEDB driver to read, and sites like Google Docs no longer support it. On the other hand `xlsx` is "just" compressed XML which doesn't even require Excel to read/write. Using libraries like EPPLus, generating a real Excel file (with colour formatting) takes only a few lines. Can you convince whoever produces these files to create proper xlsx files?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in the attached images i did exactly that.

Comment: Do you know anything about the origin of that file?